# Changing the formatting of a graph in R using ggplot2: Reorganizing the way bars are displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to modify this output graph so that each Wall and Restored bar is next to each other for each site. The wall and restored are the site types.

This is the graph that I would like it to resemble in terms of formatting the bar placements:

[image]

Here is my code and the output it produces:

```
ggplot(sed_avg_long, aes(x = Site, y = Avg_Percentage, fill = Sediment_Type))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
facet_grid(~Site_Type, scales = "fixed") +
labs(x = "Site", y = "Average Percent Sediment", fill = "Sediment type") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Please Help!

I have tried changing the facet but I can never get it right

Comment: It sounds like you want `x = Site_Type` and `facet_grid(~Site)`, so that the two site types are within facets for each Site, instead of having different sites within facets for each Site_Type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to flip-flop where you have `Site_Type` and `Site`.

Also, it's always nice to include a minimal reproducible example. I have included one below.

```
sed_avg_long <- data.frame(Site= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6),
                           Site_Type = rep(c("Restored", "Walled"), each = 3, time = 3),
                           Avg_Percentage = c(30, 40, 30, 50, 25, 25, 10, 60, 30, 10, 30, 60, 50, 10, 40, 30, 30, 40),
                           Sediment_Type = rep(c("sand", "clay", "choclate chip cookies"), time = 6))

ggplot(sed_avg_long, aes(x = Site_Type, y = Avg_Percentage, fill = Sediment_Type))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(~Site, scales = "fixed") +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Average Percent Sediment", fill = "Sediment type") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image: grouped and faceted ggplot]